# Query on uint256 and int256

Tags: solidity, dapps

need to verify something, suppose i have this:

```
uint256 a =10;
uint256 b = 20;
uint256 c;
if (b > a) {
 c = b-a;
 (-c.mul(10))  // i want to multiply with -c intentionally
}
```

this -c gonna give error, because uint256 can't be negetive. Can i do like this here?

```
uint256 a =10;
uint256 b = 20;
uint256 c;
if (b > a) {
  c = b-a;
  -int256(c);
  (c.mul(10));    // Now will c become negetive here?
}
```

Will -int256(c)` work??

And if i do `(0 - c).mul(10)`, will it work?

N.B: avoiding typecasting because i will have o change my code broadly.

Comment: why are u using safe math?? its unnecessary with in solidity 8+

Comment: What should I use then ?Normal operators like `*` and `/`?

Comment: Yes you can securely use normal operators with solidity 8+, it has it built in. The EVM will error before it under or overflows. Try it out in remix. If your trying to disable this feature you can use `unchecked { //code.. }`

Answer (score 0):

cant you do it like this?

```
function test(uint256 a, uint256 b) public pure returns (int256 c) {
    c = (b >= a) ? int256(b - a) * 10 : int256(a - b) * -10;
}
```